# How to create a cydia tweak

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode

My aim is to learn to develop jailbreak tweaks for iphone: ex `f.lux`, `Activator`, `Barrel`, `DirectionBar`...

But my problem is that I don't know where to start.  I know only some C and Objective C.

I want you to tell me what languages (Objective C, C, , C#, C++, Java...) I need to learn and what software the tweaks developers use ta make tweaks.(ex. xcode)

If possible tell me where to learn more about jailbreaking tweaks/apps(ex. e/books, website, videos...).

Please be patience with me because I am relatively new to this subject. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you begin by learning at least a minimal amount of Objectice-C so that you know at least the syntax and some of the main frameworks.

A good little starting guide I found [for beginners wanting to learn how to create jailbreak apps](http://www.ijailbreak.com/cydia/how-to-create-a-cydia-tweak/) gives you a bit of information along with links to an objective-c guide and a couple other useful guides.

Comment: Good toturial... But what I really wanted is only the part where you actually develop it more in depth - which shows you how to actually develop a tweak. If you find more toturials add the as answer. Thanks